# Raising exception with two arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Greetings again StackOverflow Community,

I was reading through a library a colleague wrote and found something that I don't quite grasp what they are trying to do. But maybe this is something I am missing with respect to Python syntax.

```
class SampleClass:
    def some_function(self) -> None:
       try:
           self.do_something()
       except CustomException as e:
           raise DifferentExceptionClass("Could not do something", e)
           # The previous line is the cause of bewilderment.

    def do_something(self) -> None:
        raise CustomException("Tried to do something and failed.")
```

I've read that raise can accept arguments but this seems to raise DifferentExceptionClass exception with a tuple as the value. What is the difference between what my colleague has done here and doing something like `raise DifferentExeptionClass("Could not do something. {}".format(e))` Is there a benefit to raising an exception his way?

The output to the function call to some_function() is:

```
test = SampleClass()
test.some_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in some_function
  File "<input>", line 10, in do_something
CustomException: Tried to do something and failed.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 6, in some_function
DifferentExceptionClass: ('Could not do something', CustomException('Tried to do something and failed.',))
```

EDIT: The colleague is unreachable for comment. Also they wrote this library a long time ago and might not remember the "mood" they were in when they wrote this. I thought it would also make a good conversation on SO in case anyone else had seen similar implementation.

Comment: No you simply call the constructor, which takes two arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely benefit to doing this. You chain exceptions and provide that chain as information to the user rather than providing the most recent exception created.

Of course, your colleague could of done it in a better way by using syntax Python provides for this. The `raise exc from raised_exc` syntax is used to raise an exception after another exception has been raised:

```
except CustomException as e:
    raise DifferentExceptionClass("Could not do something") from e
```

and causes `e` (the raised exception, `CustomException` here) to be stored as the `__cause__` attribute of the most recent exception (`DifferentExceptionClass` here) if you need to peek at it.

In the case where a `raise` is used inside an `except` handler (as happens in your code snippet), the previous exception (`e`) *is already implicitly stored* as a `__context__` attribute for it. So, passing it as an argument too, doesn't do anything else but also store the exception in the `args` tuple.

Answer (score 2):

> I've read that raise can accept arguments but this seems to raise DifferentExceptionClass exception with a tuple as the value.

`Exception`s are in fact classes as well. Indeed somewhere you will find something like:

```
class DifferentExceptionClass(Exception):

    def __init__(self,message,innerException):
        # ...
        pass
```

So you call **a constructor**. How the arguments are handled **is up to the exception**. It is possible that the message is formatted with the inner exception, but it is also possible that it does something totally different.

The advantage is for instance that the `innerException` (or other parameters) can be stored, inspected and handled accordingly. If you format the exception, the **real exception data is lost**: you only have a textual representation of it.